# How to use modules defined inside of a private package in Julia?

Tags: julia

so I have the following:

A Private Package: `PrivPack.jl`
Within `PrivPack.jl`, I have 2 modules: `mod1` and `mod2`.

In the `PrivPack.jl` file I do `include("mod1.jl")` and `include("mod2.jl")` which are the files that house the modules. However, when I try to access `mod1` anywhere in my package, I do not seem to have access to it. I either need to include the file and do `using .mod1` or I have to push the file into my loadpath using the `startup.jl` file.

What's the solution to fix this issue? I don't want to have to re-include the file every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you should just do `using .mod1, .mod2` after `include`ing the files. Otherwise, you just have modules floating around that haven't actually been loaded.

Comment: That’s what I think the right answer is as well. Waiting on a few things to test but I agree with you!